# Why is a mysqldump with single-transaction more consistent than a one without?

Tags: mysql

I have gone through the manual and it was mentioned that every transaction will add a `BEGIN` statement before it starts taking the dump. Can someone elaborate this in a more understandable manner?

Here is what I read:

> This option issues a BEGIN SQL statement before dumping data from the server. It is useful only with transactional tables such as InnoDB and BDB, because then it
>   dumps the consistent state of the database at the time when BEGIN was issued without blocking any applications."

Can some elaborate on this?

Comment: Perhaps add some links or quotes of specific parts of the manual you need help with, otherwise we're guessing a bit as to what you want to know.

Comment: I have updated the post. please have a look at.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since the dump is in one transaction, you get a consistent view of all the tables in the database.  This is probably best explained by a counterexample.  Say you dump a database with two tables, `Orders` and `OrderLines`

1. You start the dump without a single transaction.
2. Another process inserts a row into the `Orders` table.
3. Another process inserts a row into the `OrderLines` table.
4. The dump processes the `OrderLines` table.
5. Another process deletes the `Orders` and `OrderLines` records.
6. The dump processes the `Orders` table.

In this example, your dump would have the rows for `OrderLines`, but not `Orders`.  The data would be in an inconsistent state and would fail on restore if there were a foreign key between `Orders` and `OrderLines`.

If you had done it in a single transaction, the dump would have neither the order or the lines (but it would be consistent) since both were inserted then deleted after the transaction began.

Comment: You came up with a better/clearer example than I did, I think. :)

Comment: Its really a better explanation.. thanks Eric.. I have a doubt. If my dump takes an hours, how about the transaction during that 1 hour then...?        Do they be stored in buffers and flushed to disc when the dump completes....? or how it happens...?

Answer (score 7):

I used to run into problems where mysqldump without the --single-transaction parameter would consistently fail due to data being changed during the dump. As far as I can figure, when you run it within a single transaction, it is preventing any changes that occur during the dump from causing a problem. Essentially, when you issue the --single-transaction, it is taking a snapshot of the database at that time and dumping it rather than dumping data that could be changing while the utility is running.

Comment: Do you mean, During the dump all the transactions will happen only in buufers and wont get reflected or flushed to disc until the dump completes....?

Comment: I think it copies a snapshot to memory or to temporary tables and then dumps that.

Comment: @Uday Don't worry too much about *how* it does it, because it depends on all sorts of factors. The concept remains the same for all sorts of different engines, be it MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle, whatever.

Comment: The dump itself is running in a transaction (buffered). Normal database operations should be continuing as expected. If it were the other way around it would potentially lead to data being lost if it is a huge database and something fails miserably.

Answer (score 5):

This can be important for backups because it means you get all the data, exactly as it is at one point in time.

So for example, imagine a simple blog database, and a typical bit of activity might be

1. Create a new user
2. Create a new post by the user
3. Delete a user which deletes the post

Now when you backup your database, the backup may backup the tables in this order

1. Posts
2. Users

What happens if someone deletes a User, which is required by the Posts, *just after* your backup reaches #1?

When you restore your data, you'll find that you have a Post, but the user doesn't exist in the backup.

Putting a transaction around the whole thing means that all the updates, inserts and deletes that happen on the database during the backup, aren't seen by the backup.