# mysqldump --single-transaction

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm testing `--single-transaction` (ST) on my test server for backups of my mariadb server. I started dump cmd with ST option and on parallel terminals I ran 2 create table, 2 delete table ,1 insert into statements just to test what will be result. 
Result was :

1. insert statement was successful in Original DB and dump.
2. 2 create table statements were not successful.available in database but not in dump file.
3. 1 delete was successful in database and dump but 1 delete was not successful in database but that records were in the dump.

As per manual to get consistent backup I'm NOT suppose to use create,Alter,delete,rename,truncate statements. I wanted to decide to go with ST or No? My goal is to get consistent backup so doing this exercise.
Thanks in Advance...!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a mysqldump with single-transaction more consistent than a one without?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705149/why-is-a-mysqldump-with-single-transaction-more-consistent-than-a-one-without)

Comment: I read that already but  one question is as per documentation all the parallel transaction are isolated from each other then why inserted rows are part of backup? also one delete statement is which is part of backup which it shouldn’t be.